# semantic popup list width is too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am working with semantic ui and got stuck with Notification menu implementation in menu bar.

I am able to setup the popup with a list but i am getting small list item squeezed vertically , i need them to be horizontally relaxed .

Below is the html i am working with .

```
<div class="ui fixed stackable menu">
  <a class="item" href="index.php"> <img src="logo.png" class="image"></a>
  <a class="item">My Project</a>
  <div class="right menu">

   <div class="item">
     <i class="bell outline icon"></i>
     <div class="ui teal circular mini label">4</div>
     <div class="ui wide notification popup bottom transition ">
     <div class="ui link celled selection list">
       <div class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
          <a class='header'>Millan kumar</a>
          <span class='time'>2 hrs ago</span>          
          <div class='description'>Commented on <a><b>Your Post </b></a> with <a><b>Following content</b></a></div>
          <div class='extra'>Thanks you for your support</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<a class="item" href="profile.php">Profile</a>
<a class="item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('.teal.label')
      .popup({
        on: 'click'
      });
```

JS Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/jfk4wkb1/2/

I have tried putting up the things on JS Fiddle , but In there popup is not coming up even , but on my local environment popup is ok but it is vertically squeezed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jfk4wkb1/4/)

You  did not add jquery in your fiddle external resource . Also i add some padding and width to looks good .

```
<div class="ui link celled selection list"  style ="padding: 20px;width: 300px;">
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="ui fixed stackable menu">
      <a class="item" href="index.php"> <img src="logo.png" class="image"></a>
      <a class="item">My Project</a>
      <div class="right menu">

       <div class="item">
         <i class="bell outline icon"></i>
         <div class="ui teal circular mini label">4</div>
         <div class="ui wide notification popup bottom right transition ">
        <div class="ui link celled selection list"  style ="padding: 20px;width: 300px;">
           <div class='item'>
            <div class='content'>
              <a class='header'>Millan kumar</a>
              <span class='time'>2 hrs ago</span>          
              <div class='description'>Commented on <a><b>Your Post </b></a> with <a><b>Following content</b></a></div>
              <div class='extra'>Thanks you for your support</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 $('.teal.label')
      .popup({
        on: 'click'
      });
```

Comment: Thanks Minar  , it worked.. by adding padding and min-width .